# Count between months in Tableau

Tags: count, tableau-api

I am needing to count month between collect dates. I need to know if the test was run in the last 3 months. Below is the code I used but it is giving me a count of zero, but I know they had 3 of the same tests run in a year because I can see the dates. I understand the first one have a count of zero, because there is no test before that, but the count for the other should be 3, 5 respectively.

`DATEDIFF('month',[Collect Date],[Collect Date])`

```
Dates of the Tests. 
1/8/2015
4/23/2015
9/30/2015
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is possible using the `LOOKUP` function in Tableau. Keep in mind, that the result relies heavily on the data that is displayed and how it is displayed (sorted, etc).

You can create a calculated field like this:

`DATEDIFF("month",LOOKUP(ATTR([Test Date]),-1),ATTR([Test Date]))`

Which calculates the number of months between the date in the current row and the date from the prior row.

Your result will look something like this:

[image]